# add button and update sales order using netsuite

Tags: button, netsuite

I am new to netsuite,i need to update sales order by adding an item to it using a button click i had write the code for button using user event script and code for updating sales order using client script.but my client script is not working

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/currentRecord','N/record'],

function(record) {

     function buttonclick() {

            try{
                var CurrRecord = currentRecord.get();
                var recIdSO= CurrRecord.id;
                var salesOrder = record.load({
                        type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
                        id:recIdSO ,
                        isDynamic: true
                      });
                 log.debug({
                     title: 'recordid',
                     details: 'Id: ' + recIdSO
                 }); 

                    var line=salesOrder.selectNewLine({
                     sublistId: 'item'

                 });

                    salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
                            sublistId : 'item',
                            fieldId : 'item',
                            value :510 ,
                            ignoreFieldChange: true
                        });

                    salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
                        sublistId : 'item',
                        fieldId : 'amount',
                        value :100 ,
                        ignoreFieldChange: true
                    });

                    salesOrder.commitLine({
                         sublistId: 'item'
                     });
                     var recId = salesOrder.save();
                     log.debug({
                         title: 'Record updated successfully',
                         details: 'Id: ' + recId
                     });

            }catch (e) {

                         log.error({
                             title: e.name,
                             details: e.message
                         });
                     }


        }





    /**
     * Function to be executed after page is initialized.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.mode - The mode in which the record is being accessed (create, copy, or edit)
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     *
    function pageInit(scriptContext) {

    }

    /**
     * Function to be executed when field is changed.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     * @param {string} scriptContext.fieldId - Field name
     * @param {number} scriptContext.lineNum - Line number. Will be undefined if not a sublist or matrix field
     * @param {number} scriptContext.columnNum - Line number. Will be undefined if not a matrix field
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     *
    function fieldChanged(scriptContext) {

    }

    /**
     * Function to be executed when field is slaved.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     * @param {string} scriptContext.fieldId - Field name
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     *
    function postSourcing(scriptContext) {

    }

    /**
     * Function to be executed after sublist is inserted, removed, or edited.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     *
    function sublistChanged(scriptContext) {

    }

    /**
     * Function to be executed after line is selected.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     *
    function lineInit(scriptContext) {

    }

    /**
     * Validation function to be executed when field is changed.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     * @param {string} scriptContext.fieldId - Field name
     * @param {number} scriptContext.lineNum - Line number. Will be undefined if not a sublist or matrix field
     * @param {number} scriptContext.columnNum - Line number. Will be undefined if not a matrix field
     *
     * @returns {boolean} Return true if field is valid
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     *
    function validateField(scriptContext) {

    }

    /**
     * Validation function to be executed when sublist line is committed.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     *
     * @returns {boolean} Return true if sublist line is valid
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     *
    function validateLine(scriptContext) {

    }

    /**
     * Validation function to be executed when sublist line is inserted.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     *
     * @returns {boolean} Return true if sublist line is valid
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     *
    function validateInsert(scriptContext) {

    }

    /**
     * Validation function to be executed when record is deleted.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @param {string} scriptContext.sublistId - Sublist name
     *
     * @returns {boolean} Return true if sublist line is valid
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     *
    function validateDelete(scriptContext) {

    }

    /**
     * Validation function to be executed when record is saved.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {Record} scriptContext.currentRecord - Current form record
     * @returns {boolean} Return true if record is valid
     *
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    function saveRecord(scriptContext) {




    }

 return {

        saveRecord: saveRecord,
        buttonclick:buttonclick
    };

});
```

Comment: Could you share your UE script and describe how you've set up the script records and deployments?  Also, please describe what's 'not working' - what result are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: Have you tried just using a workflow/workflow script?  You can add a button via the workflow, that calls the script.  The script can then perform the action that you need to do (in this case adding a line to the SO).

Answer (score 1):

Your current example is almost correct.

You need a couple of things:

1. first add `fireSlavingSync:true` as a property for all your setCurrentLineItemValue methods. Otherwise Netsuite might not have finished updating the item's field by the time you get to your `commitLine` call.
2. I'd also tend to set `ignoreFieldChange:false`.
3. you probably need to set a price level on the line item. Depending on your version of Netsuite you should be able to just set a custom price level:

   `salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
       sublistId : 'item',
       fieldId : 'price',
       value :-1 ,
       ignoreFieldChange: false,
       fireSlavingSync:true
   });`

Comment: thanks for your help...but i had completed my task using some other method

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, if you add buttons from client script, they are only available in EDIT mode and you are trying to load same record and update it, this would result in record has been changed error message on UI(Also, NetSuite doesn't recommend this). The better way would be to use workflows to update  records.
In workflow you could add button using the workflow itself and on button click fire your workflow action script to update line item on the Order.
[Here](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4460429314.html) is sample you can refer to.

Comment: I had lost the workflow script anyway  I am success full in writing client script

Comment: hi avi.. may i have your email id

Comment: avivashisth@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/currentRecord', 'N/record'],

  function (currentRecord, record) {

    function pageInit(scriptContext) {

    }

    function buttonclick() {
      try {
        var salesOrder = currentRecord.get();
        console.log(salesOrder)
        var recIdSO = salesOrder.id;
        /*              var salesOrder = record.load({
                        type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
                        id:recIdSO ,
                        isDynamic: true
                      });*/
        /*              console.log('recordid'+ recIdSO);
        */               /*log.debug({
                           title: 'recordid',
                           details: 'Id: ' + recIdSO
                       }); */

        var line = salesOrder.selectNewLine({
          sublistId: 'item'

        });
        console.log('line' + line);

        salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'item',
          fieldId: 'item',
          value: 510,
          ignoreFieldChange: true
        });

        salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'item',
          fieldId: 'amount',
          value: 100,
          ignoreFieldChange: true
        });
        salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'item',
          fieldId: 'taxcode',
          value: -160,
          ignoreFieldChange: true
        });

        salesOrder.commitLine({
          sublistId: 'item'
        });
        var recId = salesOrder.save();
        log.debug({
          title: 'Record updated successfully',
          details: 'Id: ' + recId
        });

      } catch (e) {

        console.log('recordid' + recIdSO);
        /*log.error({
            title: e.name,
            details: e.message
        });*/
      }
    }

    return {
      pageInit: pageInit,
      buttonclick: buttonclick
    };
  });
```

Comment: Marg, can you please share how you got this to work? I'm trying to do something similar with the Client Script button definition on a script record, but for some reason it's not finding my function.  I'm returning my function buttonclick and there is a button on the page which I created on the script record with the function "buttonclick", but the code doesn't run.